# How to execute ajax post after execution of form validation on form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, jquery-plugins

I have an ajax post call which submits a contact form in my Rails application.

```
function contact_email(e){
    form = $('form');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType: "JSON",
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            window.location = data.redirect_url;
        },
        error: function(xhr, status) {
            console.log(status);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

And the accompanying html is :

```
<div class="form-container">
          <form name="contact_form" action="/contact" data-remote="true" class="forms" >
            <fieldset>
              <ol>
                <li class="form-row text-input-row name-field">
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="text-input defaultText required" title="Name (Required)"/>
                </li>
                <li class="form-row text-input-row email-field">
                  <input type="text" name="email" class="text-input defaultText required email" title="Email (Required)"/>
                </li>
                <li class="form-row text-input-row subject-field">
                  <input type="text" name="subject" class="text-input defaultText" title="Subject"/>
                </li>
                <li class="form-row text-area-row">
                  <textarea name="message" class="text-area required"></textarea>
                </li>
                <li class="form-row hidden-row">
                  <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="" />
                </li>
                <li class="button-row">
                  <input onclick="contact_email()" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-submit bm0" />
                </li>
              </ol>
              <input type="hidden" name="v_error" id="v-error" value="Required" />
              <input type="hidden" name="v_email" id="v-email" value="Enter a valid email" />
            </fieldset>
          </form>
        </div>
```

Jquery.slickforms is being used to validate the forms before submission, which essentially checks to see if required fields are filled in and does regex validation on the email provided. 
Slick forms is initiated by:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.forms').dcSlickForms();
});
```

However, when debugging the execution, my

```
onclick="contact_email()"
```

is first evaluated and a POST is made, and AFTER that only does the execution of the slickforms validation occur. How can I make it such that the contact_email() function I've bound to onsubmit occurs if and only after successful form validation by slickforms?

Comment: follow the plugin docs. they likely have some sort of submit handler

Comment: Have you tried with `$('.forms').sumbit(function(){/* ... */})`?

Comment: @maremp You mean instead of binding my function to click via onclick="contact_email()"? The issue I had with that was it double submitted and I had trouble preventing default, even with return false and e.preventDefault();

Comment: Yes, from there you can cancel actual form post, validate it and send ajax request rather than traditional form submit.

Comment: Based off my setup, what can I do to cancel the traditional submit? Because the techniques I mentioned above did not work. The other issue is that I'm not sure whether the jQuery.slick submit listener will get executed first, or my contact_email() function, because jquery.slick must execute first for the form elements to indicate whether there's an error or not.

Comment: a simple form attrib: onsubmit="contact_email(); return false;"

Comment: How can I be sure that the jquery slick forms onsubmit gets executed first rather than my function? If it doesn't, the form elements wont have the error attribute for me to do validations.

Comment: @dandavis onsubmit="contact_email(); return false;" worked to prevent double send, and my ajax was called and it was submitted succesfully, however my success callback wasn't executed, and the page was not redirected. The json response from my server came back successfully too.

Comment: sounds like you're getting closer. can async=false and a callback work together (doesn't makes sense)?

Comment: Removing async: false didn't work. And it appears now I have trouble debugging the execution of jquery.slicks onsubmit handler and mine since they're being executed concurrently.